# KKT conditions analysis for binary constraints

Tags: linear-programming, kkt-conditions, lp-relaxation, lagrange-multipliers, relaxation

I am wondering if boolean constraints in a linear program can be solved (after linear relaxation from $x\in\{0,1\}$ to both $x\ge0$ and $x\le1$) using KKT analysis.

Most of the algorithms that I have found were branch and bound-based, but I am trying to find an analytical solution using KKT conditions.

Comment: For almost all LPs (and MIPs) there are no analytical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Binary (Boolean) values are integer values. Therefore, optimization problems with boolean constraints are either integer programming or mixed integer programing (MIP).

*Generally*, there is no easy algorithm that is guaranteed to find the optimal solution of MIP problems quickly. My reason to believe that is: I can implement a boolean satisfiability (b-sat) problem as a mixed integer programming problem. That means mixed integer programming problems is a super-set of b-sat problems. Since b-sat is NP-complete, mip is NP-hard.

I think KKT condition is more like a check to see if a solution is a local optimum. I don't expect NP-hard problems to have simple analytical solution in general.

Of course, *some* problems with Boolean constraints can have analytical solution. But there is no general easy way to solve all MIP problems.